# How can I speed up a point in time DAX measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a basic data model with 4 tables: 1 fact table and 3 dimension tables. One of the dimension tables is a date table. The fact table contains c. 1.1 million rows.

This is the measure I would like to optimise, if possible:

```
VAR WeekEnding = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[FinancialWeekEnding],MAX(Dates[FinancialWeekEnding]))

RETURN
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fact),
            ALL(Dates),
            Fact[Completed Date Calculated] > WeekEnding || ISBLANK(Fact[Completed Date Calculated]),
            Fact[IssuedDate] <= WeekEnding,
            Fact[Cancelled Date Calculated] > WeekEnding || ISBLANK(Fact[Cancelled Date Calculated])
)
```

The purpose is to place to measure on a line chart with dates on the x axis and the result will show the number of open cases in the Fact table at the date - my logic is get the date at the data point, remove filters from the Dates table and then check if the case was created on or before said date and was either not cancelled or cancelled after and not closed or closed after. As I type, I wonder if REMOVEFILTERS would be quicker than ALL..

Measure currently calculates in about a minute but responded very slowly, or not at all, to slicers. Any ideas to improve this calculation time? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you use import mode, if your measure in taking a lot of time to return a value, try change the condition into columns calculated if possible at refresh time. ie : add custom column, with the expression IF(Fact[IssuedDate] <= WeekEnding,1,0). again if possible

Comment: I am not sure how that is going to produce the same result? I think I need a measure as the calculation is dynamic, dependent on the week ending in the visual. A calculated column will return a static value only

Comment: Is this an Imported model or Direct Query?
For calculated column idea, think of adding the calculated column to your date table (Open cases). - not ideal but would work.
Another approach to consider is having an aggregation table of your fact table.
Curious though on the performance as your measure isn't too tasking. If you created a simple measure like _test = COUNTROWS(Fact) -- how long does this one take?

Comment: It's imported. COUNTROWS calculates pretty much straight away. Aggregation tables I haven't used - would that be a 2 column table with all dates and the number of open cases on each? Thanks.